# Unable to prints the Names and links in python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, request, webdriver

I got stuck on extracting names and links it doesn't any response but it prints prices.

link from where I scraping is: https://sehat.com.pk/categories/Over-The-Counter-Drugs/Diarrhea-and-Vomiting-/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://sehat.com.pk/categories/Over-The-Counter-Drugs/Diarrhea-and-Vomiting-/'
r = requests.get(url)
time.sleep(6)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-md-12 pr-0 pl-0')

for property in content:


    links = property.find('div',{'class': 'col-md-12 d-table-cell align-middle'})['href']
    name= property.find('img', class_ = 'img-fluid').text.strip()
    price= property.find('div', class_ = 'ProductPriceRating d-table-cell text-center pl-1 pr-1 align-middle').text.strip()
    print(name,links,price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import csv 

url = 'https://sehat.com.pk/categories/Over-The-Counter-Drugs/Diarrhea-and-Vomiting-/'
r = requests.get(url)
# time.sleep(6)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-md-12 pr-0 pl-0')
# print(content)


header = ['url', 'item', 'price']
data = []

for property in content:
    link =[i['href'] for i in property.findAll("a")][0]


    title = [i.getText(strip=True) for i in property.find_all("a")][1]

    

    price = [i.getText(strip=True) for i in property.find_all('div',{'class':"ProductPriceRating"})][0]
    data.append([link, title, price])

print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)

df.to_csv("products.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks ,from where you find headers please locate me

Comment: Its just rename the columns nothing else. I just updated my answer.